# How get number of active users from Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics, looker-studio

I use Firebase to analyzing user data in my android project. When I want to get the number of all active users in the last 90 days, Firebase shows this chart[image]. But I don't know How many active users I have in the last 90 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in report to show the 90-day active users.

If you want to know how many users were active in the last 90 days, you'll have to export the data to BigQuery, and perform the required query there. There is a sample Google Data Studio template that looks similar to the Firebase console, which you might use as a starting point for your custom queries.